# Notify jobs when another job finishes

Tags: kotlin, jobs, kotlin-coroutines

In my application, all the requests need a token as http authorization header, which expires after a certain time. When a job gets from server with `401` status code I need to start the job to refresh the token. When this job is completed, I need to notify all the jobs from my application because I don't know which of them failed(job became completed but with 401 http status) and I must retry it with the new token.

How can I do this with coroutines?

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Also, it sounds like asking for a complete design/design idea and not a solution to one focused problem, inviting discussion instead of definite answers.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for your response. I think you are right. I wrote before these question another one :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647810/recreate-job-after-another-job-is-completed/55684928?noredirect=1#comment98055758_55684928 
Maybe these questions together can clarify my problem.

Comment: I have many classes on service layer, each one makes requests to server for certain entities. For example, MessageService send a request for retrieving all the messages from server. When it returns with 401 http status, the AuthenticationService starts a refreshToken request. I found a solution to send on refresh callback something that indicates the token was refresh with success, but this makes each job to be recreated it if receive that information from refreshToken. I am new with Coroutine and I asked if there is some way to subscribe to a job, to know when it gets completed etc.

Comment: [`job.invokeOnCompletion`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/invoke-on-completion.html) maybe?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik invokeOnCompletion is a solution, with a callback as I mentioned above. Is it possible with actor, channels? I don't know to use them.

Comment: You can also use `job.onJoin` within a `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

At first, lets define how the token gets refreshed:

1) If there is no request to refresh the token yet, start a new one

2) If there is one already going on, just wait for that.

In Kotlin that could be written as:

```
  var retrieveToken : Deferred<String>? = null

  suspend fun getToken(refresh: Boolean = false): String {
    if(retrieveToken == null || refresh && !retrieveToken.isActive)
      retrieveToken = async { API.getToken() }
    return retrieveToken.await()
  }
```

Now retrying the API gets fairly simple:

```
  suspend fun requestAPIAndRetry(api: String) {
     try {
       val token = getToken()
       val result = API.call(api, token)
     } catch(error) {
      // verifiy if it is 401
      val token = getToken(refresh = true)
      var result = API.call(api, token)
    }
 }
```

Now if the requests start failing, the following happens:

1) The first call to `getToken(refresh = true)` will start a request to the API and will return that.

2) All following calls will just get the same Deferred as the first call, therefore all requests just wait for one token update

3) If the token is there, the Deferred will resolve, and all APIs will retry (maybe even in parallel).